# How to set Midnight Commander as the default File Manager?

Tags: mime-types, file-manager, mc

I want graphical applications such as `transmission-gtk` and Firefox to open up directories with Midnight Commander through new instances of my default terminal emulator running on Debian.

I've noticed that every time I try to open a directory in various X11/GTK applications, they rather turn to my Firefox browser to show the path, and not to my file manager - MC, including Firefox itself.

I don't know what's wrong with my mimes because Midnight Commander is indeed flagged as a FileManager, and it is the only dedicated file manager that's installed on my system.

`/usr/share/applications/mc.desktop`:

```
Categories=ConsoleOnly;Utility;FileManager;System;FileTools;
Keywords=file manager;console;
```

My `mimeinfo.cache` is present at the same directory as well, however it has no mention of `mc.desktop` at all.

How can I set Midnight Commander as my default file manager to be used for opening and browsing filesystem paths? I'm using Linux Debian 10 with X11 but without a desktop environment.

Comment: I have no used debian in some time, but have you [read this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235660/how-do-i-change-the-default-file-manager-back-to-nautilus)?

Comment: @number9 I've tried `xdg-mime default mc.desktop inode/directory` (as mentioned in this article) and now basically GUI apps freeze the moment I try to open any directory through them, and I have to kill them through htop.

Comment: Ugh. I had an issue similar to that with a debian/ubuntu derivative. Truth be told after countless hours of pain, I backed up my home dir and reinstalled and fixed it by using a different method, which is not like me. What happens if you try to default it back to the stock file manager?

Comment: @number9, Firefox was used as my fallback "file manager" so I set it back to `firefox.desktop` and now it works just as before, all directories are opened via Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the file `~/.local/share/applications/mc.desktop` with contents

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Midnight Commander
MimeType=inode/directory
Exec=mc %F
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=FileManager
```

Notice the line `Terminal=true`, maybe you have missed that. MC needs to be run inside a terminal to work, differently from many other applications, as we well know.

Then issue `xdg-mime default mc.desktop inode/directory`.

I tested it on Firefox (by going to Downloads and then clicking the folder icon to open an item in its directory) and it worked like a charm.

**Edit:** The above procedure still does not work for some applications (e.g., Telegram and GNOME's Disk Usage Analyzer). Apparently, some (1) ignore or don't cope with `Terminal=true`, while others (2) pass a [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) as the file path.

To solve both issues at once, try this `mc.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Midnight Commander
MimeType=inode/directory
Exec=xterm -e mc %U
Type=Application
Categories=FileManager
```

Explanation: (1) The *Exec* takes up the job of invoking your terminal (in my case, XTerm) and then it runs `mc` in the terminal (that is what `-e` option is specifying). (2) Replacing %F with %U, URIs are correctly understood.

Comment: Only adding this `mc.desktop` to `./local/share/applications/` did not work for me, resulted in errors about `/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 811: : command not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: line 881: x-www-browser: command not found
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment. Missing chrome or resource URL: resource://gre/modules/UpdateListener.jsm`


----->  Fixed by adding `mc.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications/`.