# Use midnight commander as default file manager

Tags: fedora, i3, mc

I'm running fedora workstation 32 with i3. I'm trying to get it to use midnight commander as the default file manager. I followed the top answer on this thread [How to set Midnight Commander as the default File Manager?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492897/how-to-set-midnight-commander-as-the-default-file-manager), but it still uses gnome's Nautilus as the default. 
`xdg-mime query default inode/directory` returns `mc.desktop`, which should open midnight commander.

Comment: It returns mc.desktol

Comment: How did you determine that Nautilus is still used as default?

Comment: Nautilus opens when I click the folder button next to Firefox downloads

Comment: The last step is to provide the output of `cat ~/.local/share/applications/mc.desktop`, so we can see if there is something wrong there.

Comment: Ah yeah of course mc.desktop is as follows:
Name=Midnight Commander
MimeType=inode/directory
Exec=mc %F
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=FileManager

Comment: Please do not put that in a comment, but [edit] your question with it using code blocks. I recommend you to try the 2nd file provided in that same answer, instead of the 1st one.